# Send Keys where no element is present (Ruby Selenium-Webdriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

I'm using Selenium-Webdriver to run my automation tests in Ruby.

One of the sign-in pages for the AUT features a pop-up which is not actually part of the browser page - as such, I can't choose an element to send the required keys to (Username/Password).
The pop-up does however automatically highlight the Username field.

I was wondering if there is a way to use 'send keys' without explicitly naming an element - that way I could send the Username, Tab, Password and finally Return.

Any advice will be gratefully received

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We can't tell how you're using it because you didn't supply any code, and it doesn't sound like you read the documentation and tried things. If you tried, what did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I have added a selenium and watir to this question because those tags are needed for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You have to use `switch_to.active_element` to pass the string. For an example, I have written the below code to pass value to the text_field in the google.com

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver=Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait=10
driver.navigate.to("https://www.google.com/")
driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys 'raj'
```

But I suggest you to use WATIR which is the wrapper around ruby selenium binding where you don't have to switch to the active element, if you call send_keys on the browser object, it automatically switch to the active element. Write the below code in WATIR

```
require 'watir'
b=Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'www.google.com'
b.send_keys 'raj'
```